# Geometry node modifier input attribute assignment does not work with python script

Tags: geometry-nodes

A follow up question to [How to get Geometry nodes modifier inputs and its type using python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/247520/how-to-get-geometry-nodes-modifier-inputs-and-its-type-using-python)

But the code:

```
bpy.data.objects["Cube"].modifiers["GeometryNodes"]["Input_2_attribute_name"] = "UVMap"
```

does not work

here "UVMap" can be any attributes like points position, vertex group indicator etc. But assigning the name does not work. We cannot find the corresponding code in the script window in GUI. It only tells us the above code, which does not work. It is surely a bug. But how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Solved by

```
bpy.context.object.modifiers["SAND_MATMASK"]['Input_2_attribute_name'] = "SAND_MATMASK"
bpy.context.object.modifiers["SAND_MATMASK"].show_viewport = False
bpy.context.object.modifiers["SAND_MATMASK"].show_viewport = True
```

Comment: Please mark it as an answer as well :)