# Set group input to attribute in geometry nodes python without ops

Tags: python, geometry-nodes

I'm creating a script for data visualization and I want my data thats been loaded into an attribute to be selected for an input.

I like to write my blender code without using ops and context where possible.

How can I turn this input from a 'float' to this?
[image]

I feel like this should be possible somewhere here

```
bpy.data.node_groups['Geonodes'].inputs['Attribute']
```

I tried setting the default value as the attribute but the default value only takes float.
I can use the ops command in the console, but it's really ugly and I'd like to avoid that if possible.

```
bpy.ops.object.geometry_nodes_input_attribute_toggle(prop_path="[\"Input_3_use_attribute\"]", modifier_name="Geonodes")
```

Is this possible without ops?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure.

First, get the modifier:

```
obj = context.object # or get the object in other way
gnmod = None
for gnmod in obj.modifiers:
    if gnmod.type == "NODES":
        break
```

Then get identifier of socket. (Since "Input_3" is quite random number you have to get identifier from socket name) In my code, I create new one it if it doesn't exist, just in case:

```
inputs = gnmod.node_group.inputs
if "MyAttr" not in inputs:
    inputs.new("NodeSocketColor", "MyAttr")
id = inputs["MyAttr"].identifier
```

Then you can set use attribute and set it (Let's say you want to set vertex color "Col"):

```
gnmod[id+'_attribute_name'] = "Col"
gnmod[id+'_use_attribute'] = True
```

Comment: _use_attribute_name was what I was looking for. Awesome! thank you.

Comment: Incase anyone has the issue of the object not updating after changing modifier, you can use `obj.data.update()`

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/308016/86891 to access inputs in versions > 4.0