# Cannot set GeometryNode attribute value on creation in Python

Tags: python, geometry-nodes

I have a script to load in a bunch of points with an attribute value. I also construct a node tree with a new attribute field to multiply by the attribute value. I want this value to default at 20 but it can only be changed manually.

[image]

I have this line of code

```
bpy.data.node_groups[mod_name].inputs[2].default_value = 20
```

Now that does set the default to 20. But it's still at 0.

I can't figure out how to reset to default or set explicitly.

```
bpy.data.objects["flux"].modifiers["flux_gn"]["Input_2"] = 20
```

Doesn't work either and then the field disappears.

edit:
To be clear, I don't like using context in my code. There is a context based line of code to do this, but I don't want to use that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Crantisz'es answer:
[Set group input to attribute in geometry nodes python without ops](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/252792/60486)

```py
import bpy


def reset_to_default(mod, name):
    input = next(i for i in mod.node_group.inputs if i.name == name)
    mod[input.identifier] = input.default_value
    

mod = bpy.data.objects["flux"].modifiers["flux_gn"]
reset_to_default(mod, "Displacement")
```

Comment: That was it. Thanks my dude