# Accessing Geometry nodes Socket Names

Tags: python, geometry-nodes, interface

I'm trying to make a modifier list and for the Geometry nodes modifier, I cannot find a way to access the Socket name I have in my group input node.

[image]

I'm currently using this code.

```
for key in modifier.keys():
    if key.startswith('Socket') and not ('attribute_name' in key or 'use_attribute' in key):
        row = col.row(align=True)
        row.prop(modifier, f'["{key}"]')
```

Do you have any idea?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of [Set group input to attribute in geometry nodes python without ops](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/252791/60486) - can you confirm or deny?

Comment: Sadly I cannot make it work in my case.

Comment: @Pitiwazou there is a new syntax since 4.0 : https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/308016/86891

Comment: thank you, I made it work!

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your help guys this is the code to make it work.

```
obj = context.object
    gnmod = None
    for gnmod in obj.modifiers:
        if gnmod.type == "NODES":
            break

    # Create a dictionary to map socket identifiers to their names
    socket_names = {f"{item.identifier}_attribute_name": item.name for item in gnmod.node_group.interface.items_tree if item.in_out == "INPUT"}

    for key in modifier.keys():
        if key.startswith('Socket') and not ('_attribute_name' in key or 'use_attribute' in key):
            socket_id = key.split('_')[1]
            attr_name_key = f"Socket_{socket_id}_attribute_name"
            if attr_name_key in socket_names:
                row = col.row(align=True)
                row.prop(modifier, f'["{key}"]', text=socket_names[attr_name_key])
```

[image]